# Formatting results in SQL Server 2012 or Excel 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am having trouble with getting my output from SQL queries to be in the format I want it in. Right now I have a few queries where I do a self join to a table to compare records for accounts that fall within my criteria. A simplified example would look like this:

```
SELECT  a.Field1
       ,a.Field2
       ,a.Field3
       ,b.Field1
       ,b.Field2
       ,b.Field3
FROM Table1 a
JOIN Table1 b
    ON a.Field = b.Field
```

The output for a and b are in the same rows and I want to try and get them stacked on each other. Sometimes there are 1000's of records returned. Is there an easy way to have the b fields stacked right under the corresponding a fields? After some research I am unable to figure out an efficient way of doing this that is not completely manual and time consuming.

EDIT:

My apologies for the lack of information in my first post. This is a better representation of what one of my queries looks like.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
                ,a.Field1
                ,a.Field2
                ,a.Field3
                ,a.Field4
                ,a.Field5
                ,a.Field6
                ,b.ID
                ,b.Field1
                ,b.Field2
                ,b.Field3
                ,b.Field4
                ,b.Field5
                ,b.Field6               
  FROM Table1 a
  JOIN Table1 b
        ON a.somefield = b.somefield
        AND a.anotherfield = b.anotherfield
  WHERE a.ID > b.ID
  AND a.thisfield <> b.thisfield
  AND a.field1 = 'something'
  AND b.field1 = 'something'
```

Given the criteria where some of the fields are not necessarily equal is a union of sorts still the most logical way?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: Sounds like you want a UNION instead of a JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to have the b fields stacked right under the
>   corresponding a fields?

```
SELECT
        Field1
       ,Field2
       ,Field3
FROM (
 SELECT 
        a.Field1
       ,a.Field2
       ,a.Field3
       ,a.Field
 FROM Table1 a
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
        b.Field1
       ,b.Field2
       ,b.Field3
       ,b.Field
 FROM Table1 b
) t
ORDER BY Field ASC
```

EDIT following edit in original question:

You do need to use a UNION to get the format you want, but I would start with your current query as a CTE and use a UNION that draws from it, like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT a.ID      AS A_ID
                ,a.Field1  AS A_Field1
                ,a.Field2  AS A_Field2
                ,a.Field3  AS A_Field3
                ,a.Field4  AS A_Field4
                ,a.Field5  AS A_Field5
                ,a.Field6  AS A_Field6
                ,b.ID      AS B_ID
                ,b.Field1  AS B_Field1
                ,b.Field2  AS B_Field2
                ,b.Field3  AS B_Field3
                ,b.Field4  AS B_Field4
                ,b.Field5  AS B_Field5
                ,b.Field6  AS B_Field6
  FROM Table1 a
  JOIN Table1 b
        ON a.somefield = b.somefield
        AND a.anotherfield = b.anotherfield
  WHERE a.ID > b.ID
  AND a.thisfield <> b.thisfield
  AND a.field1 = 'something'
  AND b.field1 = 'something'
)
  SELECT
   A_ID
  ,B_ID
  ,A_Field1
  ,A_Field2
  ,A_Field3
  ,A_Field4
  ,A_Field5
  ,A_Field6
  FROM cte
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
   A_ID
  ,B_ID
  ,B_Field1
  ,B_Field2
  ,B_Field3
  ,B_Field4
  ,B_Field5
  ,B_Field6
  FROM cte
  ORDER BY A_ID, B_ID
```

If you absolutely have to stack the ID columns on top of each other in the results, then you'll need to put the UNION above in a derived table like I did in my first example.   But you need both ID's in the base UNION query to get the row-order right.

Comment: You'll have a syntax error with the "ORDER BY" in both statements.

Comment: You're right, I thought the TOP clause prevented that error, but it doesn't.   I will edit.

Comment: So I made a change to more closely represent the type  of query I want to use this for. I have tried placing the where criteria outside the union but that will not work. Is my only option to place my whole query in the from clause and use a union where I only select 'a' fields in the top and 'b' fields in the bottom? Leaving the join and where critieria in for both in the union?

Comment: Thank you for your input